# ng-repeat not working in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HN3Z9.png)I'm trying to display the data from my json file on my html page through controller using ng-repeat but it's not working. I looked for every possible errors I might have made but all my efforts went in vain.
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.
The data in json file is as follows:

```
[
            {
                "id":1,
                "name":"John",
                "company":"Infosys"
            },
            {
                "id":2,
                "name":"John2",
                "company":"Infosys2"
            },
            {
                "id":3,
                "name":"John3",
                "company":"Infosys3"
            },
            {
                "id":4,
                "name":"John4",
                "company":"Infosys4"
            },
            {
                "id":5,
                "name":"John5",
                "company":"Infosys5"
            },
            {
                "id":6,
                "name":"John6",
                "company":"Infosys6"
            },
            {
                "id":7,
                "name":"John7",
                "company":"Infosys7"
            },
            {
                "id":8,
                "name":"John8",
                "company":"Infosys8"
            }

]
```

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
    .state('tabs',{
      url:"/tab",
      abstract:true,
      templateUrl:"templates/tabs.html"
    })
    .state('tabs.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
          controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.addFriend',{
      url:"/addFriend",
      views:{
        'addFriend-tab':{
            templateUrl:"templates/addFriend.html",
            controller:'addFriendTabController'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.message',{
      url:"/message",
      views:{
        'message-tab':{
            templateUrl:"templates/message.html",
            controller:'messageTabController'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.notifications',{
      url:"/notifications",
      views:{
        'notifications-tab':{
            templateUrl:"templates/notifications.html",
            controller:'notificationsTabController'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.profile',{
      url:"/profile",
      views:{
        'profile-tab':{
            templateUrl:"templates/profile.html",
            controller:'profileTabController'
        }
      }
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/home");
})

.controller('HomeTabCtrl',function($scope){
    console.log("Home tab");
    
})
.controller('addFriendTabController',function($scope,personService){
    console.log("addFriend tab");
    $scope.persons={};
    $scope.persons=personService.getData();
      
    $scope.addFriend=function(){
      window.alert("Request Sent");
    }
})
.controller('messageTabController',function($scope){
    console.log("message tab");
})
.controller('notificationsTabController',function($scope){
    console.log("notifications tab");
})
.controller('profileTabController',function($scope){
    console.log("profile tab");
})

.factory('personService',function($http){
        var StudentDataOp = {};
        StudentDataOp.getData=function(){
          return $http.get("js/data.json").
                  then(function(response){ console.log(response.data); return response.data;})
        };

        return StudentDataOp;
  })
```

```html
<body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <div class="bar bar-positive item-input-inset headerBorder">          
          <label class="item-input-wrapper positive-bg" id="headerSearch">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon searchIcon"></i>
            <input type="search" placeholder="People, jobs, posts and more...">
          </label>
          <a href="#"><i class="icon ion-grid placeholder-icon searchIcon"></i></a>
      </div>

      <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

      <script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">         
          <ion-tabs tabs-swipable class="tabs-icon tabs-positive tabs-top tab-top" on-swipe-left="onSwipeLeft()" on-swipe-right="onSwipeRight()">

            <ion-tab icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
              <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>

            <ion-tab icon="ion-person-stalker" href="#/tab/addFriend">
              <ion-nav-view name="addFriend-tab"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>

            <ion-tab icon="ion-chatboxes" ui-sref="tabs.message">
              <ion-nav-view name="message-tab"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>

            <ion-tab icon="ion-android-notifications" ui-sref="tabs.notifications">
              <ion-nav-view name="notifications-tab"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>

            <ion-tab icon="ion-person" ui-sref="tabs.profile">
              <ion-nav-view name="profile-tab"></ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>

          </ion-tabs>  
      </script> 

      <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
          <ion-content class="has-tabs-top">
            <div class="list card">
              <div class="item item-thumbnail-left">           
                <img src="img/ionic.png">
                <h2 class="listCss">Name</h2>
                <h3>Followers</h3>
                <p>Time</p>          
              </div>
              <div class="item item-image">
                <img src="img/NIKHIL.jpg">
              </div>  
              <a href="#" class="item assertive">Click here...</a>
            </div>        
          </ion-content>
       </script>

       <script id="templates/addFriend.html" type="text/ng-template">            
          <ion-content class="has-tabs-top">
            <div class="button-bar" style="padding-top: 3%;">
              <a class="button button-light connection-button-1 connection-button-2">181 Connections</a>
              <a class="button button-light connection-button-1"><p>
                  <i class="icon ion-plus placeholder-icon addConnection"></i>
                  Find Conncetions</p></a>              
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: #E6E6E6;overflow: overlay;">
              <div style="background-color: white;margin: 15px 0px;padding: 5px;">
                  No Pending Invitations
                  <div style="float: right;font-weight: 500;margin-right:10px">MANAGE ALL</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <h4 style="color: #387ef5;">People You May Know</h4>
              
              <div ng-hide="hidden" data-ng-repeat="person in persons">
                <div class="item item-thumbnail-left">                           
                <img src="img/ionic.png">
                <div style="float: left;">
                <h2 class="listCss">{{person.name}}</h2>
                <h3>{{person.company}}</h3>
                <p>{{persons.id}}</p> 
                 
                </div>
                <div style="float: right;padding-top: 20px;padding-right: 20px;">
                <i class="icon ion-close-circled addConnection" style="font-size:40px;padding-right: 10px;" ng-click="hidden=!hidden"></i>
                <i class="icon ion-person-add addConnection" style="font-size: 40px;" ng-click="addFriend()"></i>
                </div>
                <hr style="clear: both;top: 26px;position: relative;">              
              </div>             
             
              </div>
            </div>
          </ion-content>
       </script>

       <script id="templates/message.html" type="text/ng-template">

       </script>

       <script id="templates/notifications.html" type="text/ng-template">

       </script>

       <script id="templates/profile.html" type="text/ng-template">

       </script>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
```

Comment: What does your console.log prints?

Comment: I think the data is in `StudentDataOp.getData` and not in `StudentDataOp`

Comment: If you check the factory I made, I've already written the console.log statement and prints the array of objects from my json file

Comment: @Mitesh It will be {{person}} only. And the data is in StudentDataOp.getData(). I've already invoked this method in my controller

Comment: did you try to print `{{persons}}` in your html ?

Comment: I've also attached the snapshot from the dev's tool

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with `ngRepeat`. The problem is in your controller.
This line is not correct:

```
$scope.persons=personService.getData();
```

The service call does not return persons data, it returns a promise object. So, it should be written like this:

```
personsService.getData().then(function(persons) {
  $scope.persons = persons;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the promise concept of factory

Comment: The promise concept has nothing to do with the factory, FYI. It is just the return type of `$http().then()`. `$http`, by itself, also returns a promise object.